# How to create a list of sentences in C

Tags: c

I am wondering what the best way is to store a series of sentences in c. In python it is quite easy but I am having trouble figuring out a similar solution in C.

For example:

```
sent1="this is sentence 1"
sent2="this is sent 2"
```

to make a list

```
list = [sent1;sent2];
```

This goal is to print a random sentence so

```
print list[random_number]
```

Comment: Use an array of `const char*` values, assuming that your strings are literals. If they're not, it gets much more complicated.

Comment: See chapter 5.6 of K&2 2nd edition.

Comment: what is K&2? 
and would i do const char* list[2] = [sent1,sent2]?

Answer (score 0):

If the sentences are static like in your example, you could simply do this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
int main()
{
   time_t t;
   const char * sentences[] = {"first sentence", "second sentence"};
   srand(time(&t));
   printf("%s\n", sentences[rand() % 2]); 
   return 0;
}
```

And Cong Ma is referring to The C Programming Language by K&R: https://hassanolity.files.wordpress.com/2013/11/the_c_programming_language_2.pdf